# Below code where (? extends aClass) is used has confused me

Tags: java, generics

As per my understanding(which needs correction obviously) the map should take Integer class and all of its sub classes. and same with Location class.

```
Map<? extends Integer, ? extends Location> test2 = new HashMap<>();
test2.put(new Integer(5), new Location(1, "Test2", exits));
```

I have watched and read from many different resources. But I still can't get my head around this. 
I am not a professional programmer.

Comment: A `List<? extends Fruit>` could be a List<Fruit>, or a List<Banana>, or a List<Apple>. the point is: you don't know. And since you don't know, you can't add anything to it because adding a Banana to a List<Apple> would be wrong. So a List<? extends Fruit> is only useful when all you care about is that you want to **read** from the list, and have the guarantee that all the elements are fruits.

Comment: `? extends Integer` means "some unknown, *specific* subclass of `Integer`.

Comment: Further to @JBNizet’s comment, I can’t stress highly enough : if you are learning generics and/or OOP principles, do NOT try to learn using classes like Integer or Number, nor anaemic names like classA, etc.  people run into so much confusion with those.  Far FAR better is to follow the example in the comment and learn creating real-world types like Fruit, Animals, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [Oracle Docs for generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html)

> You can use an upper bounded wildcard to relax the restrictions on a variable. For example, say you want to write a method that works on `List<Integer>`, `List<Double>`, and `List<Number>`; you can achieve this by using an upper bounded wildcard.

and

> The upper bounded wildcard, `<? extends Foo>`, where `Foo` is any type, matches Foo and any subtype of Foo. The process method can access the list elements as type Foo:

So basically `test2` is a `Map` which takes the key as Integer or any class which has extended Integer(i.e subclasses of Integer) and the value as `Location` or its subclass

Answer (score 0):

This can be explained better with small example, let's take a method with generic argument of `Map`

```
public static void m1(Map<? extends Number, ? extends Object> test2) {

}
```

Now you can create `Map` objects with key as `Number` or it's child classes and value as `Object` or it child classes and call that method

```
    Map<Integer, String> map1 = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    m1(map1);

    Map<Double, String> map2 = new HashMap<Double, String>();
    m1(map2);

    Map<Number, StringBuffer> map3 = new HashMap<Number, StringBuffer>();
    m1(map3);

    Map<Integer, StringBuilder> map4 = new HashMap<Integer, StringBuilder>();
    m1(map4);
```

`? extends Number` doesn't mean map can contains `Number` or it's child object, it means either you can create `Map` with key as `Number` or it's child's. which is the same for value also `? extends Object` either `Object` or it's child's